# Laravel 5.1 deleting sub-relationship data when row is deleted

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I have an application in Laravel 5.1 where the following tables are setup;

- timesheet
- row
- day_total
- segment_totals

Rows belong to timesheets.
Day totals belong to timesheets.
Segment totals belong to rows.

When a timesheet is deleted, I also want it to delete the rows from `row`, `day_total` and `segment_total` as well as the row from `timesheet` table itself.

I hav setup the following boot method in my `timesheet` model;

```
/**
 * Boot the model.
 *
 */
public static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    static::deleting(function($timesheet)
    {
        $timesheet->row()->delete();
        $timesheet->dayTotal()->delete();
    });
}
```

I have setup the following in the `row` model;

```
/**
 * Boot the model.
 *
 */
public static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    static::deleting(function($row)
    {
        $row->day()->delete();
        $row->segmentTotal()->delete();
    });
}
```

When the timesheet is deleted, the `row` and `dayTotal` rows are deleted, but the `day` and `segmentTotals` do not get deleted.  How can I make Laravel fire the delete on the `row` model?

Comment: could you please post your Entity and the relationships since it seems the problematic Models are not related to each other in MYSQL?

Answer (score 0):

When you call `delete()` on the relationship query, it runs a direct query against the database to delete the records. Because of this, the related models are not loaded, and the `deleting` events on those models cannot be called. You need to delete the records in a way where the events on the related models can be called.

You either need to loop through the related models and call `delete()` on each model instance, or you can get a list of the related ids, and then use the `destroy()` method (which just loads the model for each id and calls `delete()` on it).

Option 1: Loop through the related models

```
public static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    static::deleting(function($timesheet)
    {
        foreach($timesheet->row()->get() as $row) {
            $row->delete();
        }
        foreach($timesheet->dayTotal()->get() as $dayTotal) {
            $dayTotal->delete();
        }
    });
}
```

Option 2: Use `destroy()` with the ids:

```
public static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    static::deleting(function($timesheet)
    {
        // getRelated() method gets the related model from the relationship.
        // This is so you don't have to hardcode \App\Row::destroy()
        // or \App\DayTotal::destroy()

        $ids = $timesheet->row()->lists('id')->all();
        $timesheet->row()->getRelated()->destroy($ids);

        $ids = $timesheet->dayTotal()->lists('id')->all();
        $timesheet->dayTotal()->getRelated()->destroy($ids);
    });
}
```